# Prove if f(x+1) - f(x) > 0 as $x\to\infty$, then f(x) is unbounded and $\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to prove that for a continuous function $f: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ if $g(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)$ and $\limsup_{x\to\infty}{g(x)} > 0$ and $\liminf_{x\to\infty}{g(x)} > 0$ then $f(x) \to \infty$.

By now, I am stuck trying to prove the opposite is impossible:
consider a sequence of closed intervals [m, m+1] as $m \to \infty$. If $f(x)$ is bounded, then there should be $l$ so that $\inf_{[l, l+1]}{f(x)} = f(l+1)$ $\Longrightarrow$ $f(l+1) - f(l) \leq 0$.

And here I am stuck, I do not know how correctly prove that there should be such a closed interval with $\inf_{[l, l+1]}{f(x)} = f(l+1)$.

Could you please help by giving me an advise or hint so that I can go further? Thank you all!

Comment: What are you trying to prove? The title is misleading.

Comment: Hi, Maxence1402, I have edited the title. I am trying to prove that the function $f(x) \to \infty$ because for $f(x+1) - f(x)$ upper and lower limits are positive.

Comment: @mur_tm the title actually says "unbounded". Are you trying to prove unboundedness or that the limit is infinity?

Comment: dfnu, let's keep both because it's related. I've amended the title.

Comment: ratio test gives this almost directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct proof is possible. Having $\lim\inf_{x\to\infty}g(x)>0$ does not only imply $g(x)>0$ for $x>A$, but also $g(x)>m$ for every $m<\lim\inf_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ and $x>A_m$.

Pick $m$ strictly positive, then reasoning with induction yields $f(A_m+n)>f(A_m)+nm$ with $n$ positive integer. But $f(A_m)+nm\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}+\infty$
Therefore, by lower bound, $f(A_m+n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}+\infty$ and $f$ is unbounded.
Since $f$ is continuous, you get $f(x)\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}+\infty$

Note that you don't need continuity to prove that $f$ is unbounded.

Comment: Maxence1402, could you check I understand correctly?
Because $f(x+1) - f(x) > 0$ for x > A for some big enough $A$, if we pick a positive  > A, then, for example, for =4 we have:
$f(m+4) > f(m+3) > f(m+2) > f(m+1) > f(m)$
So as $n \to \infty$ we get $f(m + n) \to +\infty$.

And if $f(x)$ is not continuous than we should not expect it be "smooth" on the intervals $(f(m), f(m+n))$, though we still have $f(x)$ unbounded because of all said above.

Thank you!

Comment: @mur_tm There, I edited my answer. Simply having $f(A_m+4)>f(A_m+3)>...>f(A_m)$ is not enough (don't confuse $m$ which lies in the output of $g$ with $A_m$ which lies in the input of $g$). Since $f(x+1)-f(x)>m$ for $x>A_m$ you have $f(A_m+3)>f(A_m+2)+m>f(A_m+1)+2m>f(A_m)+3m$ etc. Recurrence yields $f(A_m+n)>f(A_m)+nm$.

Comment: By recurrence, I meant induction. Sorry, translation problems happen sometimes :/

Comment: Oh, I got, if I just have $(+4)>(+3)>...>()$, then I cannot be sure it goes to $\infty$. I understood all details. Thank you so much!